# Calculate ratio in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate the ratio of group 1: group(>1) in the same year, my dataframe has the following format:

| Group | Year | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021 | 4 |
| 2 | 2020 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021 | 6 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021 | 3 |

The result should be like this:

| Year | Ratio |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3/7 |
| 2021 | 4/9 |

I'm really stuck with this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide DataFrame with `1` value in `group` by aggregate all another groups aggregatet by `sum`:

```
#if need equal
m = df['Group'].eq(1)
#if need greater
m = df['Group'].gt(1)
a = df[~m].set_index('Year')['Count'].div(df[m].groupby('Year')['Count'].sum())
print (a)
Year
2020    0.428571
2021    0.444444
Name: Count, dtype: float64


df1 = a.reset_index(name='Ratio')
print (df1)
   Year     Ratio
0  2020  0.428571
1  2021  0.444444
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
# get sum per Group+Year
df2 = df.groupby(['Group', 'Year']).sum()

# divide 1st group by sum of others
out = (df2.loc[1].div(df2.drop(1).groupby(level='Year').sum())
       #.reset_index() # optional, uncomment if you want Year as column
       )
```

output:

```
         Count
Year          
2020  0.428571
2021  0.444444
```